# In high chart how to add event for label click

Tags: highcharts

In high chart there is an event for clicking on the bar. But bar is small in height it is impossible to click on it. Hence I want the event in high chart for further processing.

E.g. I want the event for month name in following example.
[image]

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use JQuery you can use it as follows

```
chart.xAxis[0].labelGroup.element.childNodes.forEach(function(label)
{
    label.style.cursor = "pointer";
    label.onclick = function(){
      alert('You clicked on '+this.textContent);
    }
});
```

complete code at http://jsfiddle.net/t07ok5v3/5/

Comment: Thnx great tip and help.How did you get to know about this method ? did you inspect elements of highchart and tried out? Because I could n't find any related document about this label and ticks event setting from their API docs.

Comment: Yes; Hope they don't break it in future releases.

Comment: hehe If they do that.. what to do.. re-inspect and do changes :*)

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution, maintained since Highcharts v3 is to use [Custom Events](https://github.com/blacklabel/custom_events/) plugin. Plugin adds a lot of new event, natively not supported by Highcharts.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Utx8g/963/

Events are added the same way as official events in Highcharts, and we don't need to re-inspect every release the DOM:

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    events: {
      click: function () { ... }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach' when running the solution from Malay Sarkar in Internet Explorer. Here's a workaround I used which works in both Chrome and IE.

```
for (let i = 0; chart.xAxis[0].labelGroup.element.childNodes.length; i++)
{
    chart.xAxis[0].labelGroup.element.childNodes[i].onclick = function(){
      alert('You clicked on '+this.textContent);
    }
});
```

Comment: or you could transpile the code down or polyfill, since Array.forEach isn't universally available if you must support older browsers.